# How to display an array as a matrix with property line

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I'm writing an app on TypeScript
I am using JSON array like:

```
data = [{"name":"dog",
        "line":1},
        {"name":"cet",
        "line":1},
        {"name":"red",
        "line":2},
        {"name":"green",
        "line":2},
        {"name":"elephant",
        "line":1}]
```

I want to arrange it on the HTML page such that each object is in the row that appears in its "line" all the object in each "line" will be in a separate row.

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data" >
   <div *ngFor="" class= "row">
      <span >{{d.name}}</span>
   <div> 
<div>
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON, did you miss the square brackets?

Comment: also invalid html (no closing div tags) and invalid second ngFor directive

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Angular Flex Layout to align things in a row or column (https://github.com/angular/flex-layout).

```
data = [
   {"name":"dog",
    "line":1},
    {"name":"cet",
    "line":1},
    {"name":"red",
    "line":2},
    {"name":"green",
    "line":2},
    {"name":"elephant",
    "line":1} ];
```

```
<div fxLayout="column">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let d of data">
    <div fxFlex fxLayout="row">
      <span>{{d.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```